# SQL - Adding a count if Statement

Tags: sql, count

I'm a relatively new SQL user so please bear with me :)

My current query is as follows...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  DMA.Name, 
  CLI.CNum, 
  CLI.LNum, 
  CLI.TSC, 
  CLI.FromDate, 
  CLI.ToDate
FROM PurchasedSites INNER JOIN
  CLI ON PS.CNum = CLI.CNum INNER JOIN
  S ON PS.SID = S.SID INNER JOIN
  DMA ON S.DMA = DMA.ID INNER JOIN
  PSM ON PS.PSID = PSM.PSID INNER JOIN
  C ON CLI.CNum = C.CNum
WHERE (PSM.MT_bmID = 10) AND 
  (CLI.FromDate <= '2013-03-31') AND 
  (CLI.ToDate >= '2013-03-01') AND 
  (S.DMA IN ('134', '113', '38', '147', '169', '24', '50', '198', '9', '55')) AND 
  (C.CS LIKE 'Active') AND 
  (PS.CNum Like 'C%') AND 
  (CLI.TSC >= 1)
```

I would like it to COUNT the number of S.SID (or it could be PS.SID - it's the same data) if PS.DC = 1.  If there are PS.DC = 1, then it can return a number of 0.

I'm not sure where to fit this in or have it written properly.  Current results look like...

```
Name              CNum     LNum   TSC   FromDate     ToDate
Detroit, MI       C147157   22     2    2013-03-18   2013-06-10 
Atlanta, GA       C146525   112    2    2013-01-28   2013-03-03 
Washington, DC    C146538   20     1    2013-02-06   2013-03-05
Los Angeles, CA   C146119   45     3    2013-01-01   2013-11-30
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to count the entries where PS.DC = 1, but not the entries where PS.DC is anything else?

```
SELECT DMA.Name, 
CLI.CNum, 
CLI.LNum, 
CLI.TSC, 
CLI.FromDate, 
CLI.ToDate,
SUM(CASE WHEN PS.DC = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS CountDC
FROM PurchasedSites PS
INNER JOIN CLI ON PS.CNum = CLI.CNum 
INNER JOIN S ON PS.SID = S.SID 
INNER JOIN DMA ON S.DMA = DMA.ID 
INNER JOIN PSM ON PS.PSID = PSM.PSID 
INNER JOIN C ON CLI.CNum = C.CNum
WHERE PSM.MT_bmID = 10
AND CLI.FromDate <= '2013-03-31'
AND CLI.ToDate >= '2013-03-01'
AND S.DMA IN ('134', '113', '38', '147', '169', '24', '50', '198', '9', '55') 
AND C.CS LIKE 'Active'
AND PS.CNum Like 'C%'
AND CLI.TSC >= 1
GROUP BY DMA.Name, 
CLI.CNum, 
CLI.LNum, 
CLI.TSC, 
CLI.FromDate, 
CLI.ToDate
```

UPDATED:  Used SUM(CASE...) because PS.DC is a bit type, which cannot be summed.

Comment: Sorry - should have clarified - PS.DC is only either a 1 or a 0, which is why I want to count only the 1's.

Comment: @user2390790 I have updated my answer - in this case this shouldn't even need a CASE statement.  We can just sum up PS.DC.  Then, of course, I realized that I meant SUM() instead of COUNT() all along.  COUNT() won't give the right answer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Just for reference, the more general approach would have been SUM(CASE WHEN PS.DC = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumEntries

Comment: This makes sense, however I have it exactly as written and it's given me an error "Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator"  Hmmm

Comment: The bit type should still work in the CASE statement, though, so you should be able to use that.  If SQL Server still thinks it's a bit type, you could make the output values into floating point numbers, e.g., SUM(CASE WHEN PS.DC = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS NumEntries.  Or else use CAST or CONVERT.

Comment: @user2390790 does using the CASE statement, or a CONVERT, do anything to get around the bit type SUM issue?

Comment: OK, so it seems I was able to get past the bit type issue using the Sum Case, however I've run into an another issue.

Comment: See if you can follow me here... CLI.CNum is an order.  CLI.LNum is an a order line within the order (there can be many order lines within the order, all of them are distinct within each order).  Within each order lines, we need to fulfill a quantity of our product (CLI.TSC).  PS.DC tells us what we have fulfilled.  When I run the above query, instead of order line 1 showing 5 and order line 2 showing 12, it's adding them all together and showing order line 1 as 17 AND order line 2 as 17.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @user2390790 Normally the GROUP BY CNUM, LNUM should take care of this. But look at the join structure: FROM PurchasedSites PS INNER JOIN CLI ON PS.CNum = CLI.CNum INNER JOIN C ON CLI.CNum = C.CNum. This means you can have a PS for each CNum. Two corresponding LNum entries then duplicates everything, but they cannot give you separate entries for PS. You would have to join on PurchasedSites.LNum (instead of CNum). If there is no PS.LNum, the database structure may have a problem, or you may be trying to do something it's not intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the data has only 1 and 0 just SUM it.  If the data has other values and you only want to count the 1's, consider a CASE statement similar to the following...

```
SELECT SUM(CASE PS.DC WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS colName
```

Comment: This also makes sense, however when I put this in, it's combining all the PS.DC's from each of the CLI.LNum together for each row (instead of it saying it's correct number, it's adding a 1 for each of the DC's within that LNum, making the number something like 61 instead of 5.  Hmmmm...

Comment: It is probably a fairly simple error in the query, but it is hard to do without a test environment.  Can you post the DDL to create the tables and just enough INSERTs to give us some test data?  Once we're looking at the same thing, this will go much easier.